# I want the last cell in a table to trigger a conditional format in excel (en masse)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Okay so I have a sheet of over 500 entries. Essentially when the pulldown menu I have placed in cell J matches the value in A$528(Set to YES) then columns A-I all have a pattern applied to them in that specific row.

What it ideally each line should look like is this:

Applies to: =$A$524:$I$524

Formula: =$J$524=$A$528

The problem is that when I had to go in and format these lines with the painter, the line Formula: =$J$524=$A$528 is Formula: =$J$2=$A$528 in all cases. =$J$2 stays completely static, I need it to progress based on which row it is in. I would really rather not have to go in and manually input these 500 numbers if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it stays static is that you use the dollar sign. If you want it to progress based on which row it is in, then just omit the dollar sign before the row. (As far as I understand your problem)

Answer (score 0):

I agree question is not crystal clear but I think what you want may be a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=$J1=$A$528
```

with Applies to of:

```
=$A$1:$I$524
```

or maybe as above but with $J2 for $J1 and $A$2 for $A$1.

The trigger value *might* be hardcoded with the formula `=$J1="YES"` instead and then no need for `YES` in `$A$528`.